# What is the draw knife technique with pencil marks called?

Tags: terminology, traditional-techniques, draw-knife

I've seen someone shape a piece of wood with a draw knife by marking the wood in places with a pencil, then drawing the knife over the area until the mark was gone. Then repeating. He seemed to be doing this with relatively high accuracy results with respect to shape. He was also using a piece of paper and other measuring tools to monitor his outcome.

I have attempted to find youtube videos of this, but haven't found any that do this particular thing.

What is the draw knife technique with pencil marks called?

(I believe he was making scale model boat spars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called marking your wood with a pencil, it's just a thing you can do with pencils.

For example, if you're going to make a cut with a saw, you might pencil in a line and then cut there. Or if you're going to sand/scrape a surface evenly, you might scribble pencil all over it then sand the marks off.

If you're going to shape something with a drawknife, a logical way to proceed might be to mark your goals then shape until you get there.

You won't be able to find videos specifically about this technique because marking things with e.g. pencils is sort of a given.

Your best bet is to keep finding shaping / carving videos until you find one shot by somebody who decided to use a pencil. Or just try it. Put a pencil mark on a piece of wood then practice cutting to it with a drawknife.

Comment: the way this person was going about it seemed very specific, measured, calculated, etc - with fairly exacting results. but i get the point.